# 500 Internal Server Error IIS7 Encoded url

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Im using N2Cms and am looking in to some issues i have with it.  It has a navigation panel on the left hand side that loads via ajax as you expand the tree.

The code that gets the childeren of the node calls an ashx file with some parameters.  One parameter is for a path and contains slashes in it.  For this reason it has been encoded.

```
.../cms/Content/Navigation/LoadTree.ashx?target=preview&selected=%252fhome%252fhelp-and-advice%252f
```

I have had no issues with this on my development server (running iis 7.5) but when deployed to our test server (iis7) the navigation fails to work.

Investigating this has shown that the above url gives a 500 error.

If i decode the url to

```
.../cms/Content/Navigation/LoadTree.ashx?target=preview&selected=/home/help-and-advice/
```

it works with no problems.

Unfortunately i cannot change the code that generates this as its a part of the n2cms source code and i am assuming it has been encoded for a good reason.

Does anyone know anything i can do either in my web.config to allow encoded parameters or something i can change on the iis server?

**EDIT:**
So this link seems to suggest that its doing this on purpose as a security mesure.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542.aspx

The suggested solution is to upgrade to .net 4.0 and add the following to the web.config

```
<configuration>
 <uri>
   <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
   </schemeSettings>
 </uri>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately this seems to have no effect.

Any Ideas why this doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the URLScan utility. URL Scan blocks URL's based on the rules in it's config file. It also has it's own log file, so you can tell for sure by looking at the URLScan log.

Do a google search for URLSCan default location.

Comment: URLScan seems to be an iis addon.  I dont think we have it installed.  I cant fine it in the add remove programs or the windows features.

Comment: Check here C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlscan or here C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\urlscan.  The location depends upon whether you are running 64 bit.   If urlscan exists in one of those locations & there is a "logs" subdirectory, then you are running it.

Comment: As i said, its not installed. Those folders dont exist and neither does any reference to urlscan in any file or folder on the machine.

Comment: Are there any errors in the server event log related to the 500 error?

Comment: This is actually very odd.  I have checked in my iis log files, i can see all the other request coming through - requests for css files, images, page loads etc.  All with their statuses like 200 or what ever.  BUT no 500 error.  I do not see the request in the log for this url! very odd

Answer (score 1):

It seems your url goes through 2 html encode.
Is there some url rewriting module active on your IIS7 server ?

Comment: Not that i am aware of.  It is a standard windows web server 2008 installation (with iis7).  I think this is a "feature" of iis7 as a simmilar standard installation with the same code on iis7.5 doesnt have this "feature".

Answer (score 0):

OK, im getting somewhere with this.

When trying to find the error in the IIS logs and failing, then looking through many posts about failed tracing request and still not getting any errors in iis, i figured that the request was just not getting to IIS.

Looking back at the server error, there was a clue there too.
    500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter.

It is the firewall!! 
We have disabled the HTTP Filter and now it works :)

I now need to investigate what this HTTP Filter was supposed to be protecting us against and are we secure now we have switched it off.